# Are questions from sci fi animation movies off-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

We have many animation movies which have sci fi and fantasy elements as:

- Megamind
- The Incredibles
- Monsters
- Shrek
- Wall E, etc

Are questions from these off-topic?

Comment: Anime are Japanese animated productions featuring hand-drawn or computer animation. Animation means animation movies in general. That's why i explicitly asked.

Comment: I'm aware of the distinction (although anime also refers to non-Japanese animation based upon the same style). However, anime is a subset of animation. If sci-fi/fantasy anime is on topic, then clearly animation other sci-fi/fantasy is also on topic.  Note that the [answer to the question I linked](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/644/1359) explicitly says `Your question breaks down to "is (media) on topic"? And the answer is, "Yes, if it's Sci-fi or Fantasy."`

Answer (score 10):

We have already had questions on all of those.. Currently, none have been closed as off-topic.

- [Megamind](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=megamind+is%3Aquestion)
- [The Incredibles](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=the+incredibles+is%3Aquestion)
- [Monsters Inc](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=monsters+inc+is%3Aquestion)
- [Shrek](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=shrek+is%3Aquestion)
- [Wall-E](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=wall-e+is%3Aquestion)

Comment: Also, [this](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/24077/how-does-mickey-mouses-upslide-work)

Answer (score 6):

I'll post the answer that @Beofett commented on (sorry for stealing!)

- The media used to tell the story is irrelevant to whether something is on or off topic.
- If animation movie content is Sci Fi or Fantasy using the commongly held definitions of this site, then it's on-topic. Otherwise, no.

Comment: Where can I find the "commonly held definitions of this site" for "SciFi or Fantasy"? (The union, not the boundary between them.) I looked for it once but lost patience before finding it.

Answer (score 1):

No.

Body must be at least 30 characters, you entered 3.

Comment: The simple answer to this Yes/No question was No. Meaning, no they are not off topic.

Comment: Duh, brain cramp sorry.